# How to override Py_GetPrefix(), Py_GetPath()?

Tags: c++, python, api

I'm trying to embed the Python interpreter and need to customize the way the Python standard library is loaded. Our library will be loaded from the same directory as the executable, not from prefix/lib/.

We have been successful in making this work by manually modifying sys.path after calling Py_Initialize(), however, this generates a warning because Py_Initialize is looking for site.py in ./lib/, and it's not present until after Py_Initialize has been called and we have updated sys.path.

The Python c-api docs *hint* that it's possible to override Py_GetPrefix() and Py_GetPath(), but give no indication of how. Does anyone know how I would go about overriding them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set `Py_NoSiteFlag = 1`, call `PyInitialize` and import site.py yourself as needed.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using `putenv` to adjust `PYTHONPATH` before calling Py_Initialize?

Answer (score 4):

I see it was asked long ago, but I've just hit the same problem. `Py_NoSiteFlag` will help with the site module, but generally it's better to rewrite `Modules/getpath.c`; Python docs [officially recommend](http://docs.python.org/c-api/intro.html#embedding-python) this for “[a]n application that requires total control.” Python does import some modules **during** initialization (the one that hit me was `encodings`), so, unless you don't want them or have embedded them too, the module search path has to be ready **before** you call `Py_Initialize()`.

From what I understand `Py_GetPath` merely returns module search path; `Py_GetProgramFullPath` is self-describing; and `Py_GetPrefix` and `Py_GetExecPrefix` are not used by anyone, except some mysterious “`ILU`”.

Answer (score 1):

The following functions can be called before calling Py_Initialize():

- Py_SetProgramName()
- Py_SetPythonHome()
- Py_SetPath()

All of these affect the way Python finds modules. I recommend reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#) on these functions and playing around with them.